# Server 404 NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

I created a server and connected it with MongoDB when I made an API in the index.js File, it is coming, but when I created an function for the same and made an API in another file and exported to index.js Its coming 404 server error

This is my index.js file

```
import express from "express";
import Connection from "../backend/connection.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import calling from "./data/routes/route.js";

dotenv.config();
const USERNAME = process.env.DB_USERNAME;
const PASSWORD = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;

const PORT = 5000;
const app = express();
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started on Port ${PORT}`);
});

Connection(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

calling();
```

This is my route.js file

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();

const calling = () => {
  app.get("/blogs", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Yes");
  });
};

export default calling;
```

Here is the pic of the error

[image]

Tried to surf in google but not found anything

Comment: You are using two different app objects one in your route and one in index.js file,thats not the right way

Comment: Okay I tried to export the app object and import it in the route.js error is coming cannot access app before initialization.

Comment: try the answer i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different app objects one in your route and one in index.js file

Try the below answer instead if you want to keep things this way otherwise see [this](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

```
import express from "express";
import Connection from "../backend/connection.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import calling from "./data/routes/route.js";

dotenv.config();
const USERNAME = process.env.DB_USERNAME;
const PASSWORD = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;

const PORT = 5000;
const app = express();
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started on Port ${PORT}`);
});

Connection(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

calling(app);
```

Your route.js file

```
const calling = (app) => { // app object passed as an argument from the index.js
  // register all your routes here ,its the same app object that is used to start the server

  app.get("/blogs", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Yes");
  });
};

export default calling
```